# How to get name of current theme in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I was trying to get the current theme applied to the site. I tired with different ways to get it but no luck.

1) `SPTheme theme1 = SPTheme.OpenAppliedTheme(SPContext.Current.Web);`

2) `string theme = SPContext.Current.Web.Theme;` (Obsolute)

3) `using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example.com/"))`

`using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)`

`using (ThmxTheme theme = ThmxTheme.Open(site, ThmxTheme.GetThemeUrlForWeb(web)))
   {
       theme.Name = "My Theme";
   }`

Is there any way to get the name?

Answer (score 0):

Get Theme collection from site :

```
ReadOnlyCollection<ThmxTheme> themes = ThmxTheme.GetManagedThemes(site);

foreach (ThmxTheme theme in themes)
{
    if (theme.Name == themeName)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Get the current theme

```
string themeUrl = ThmxTheme.GetThemeUrlForWeb(web);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(themeUrl))
{
    ThmxTheme currentTheme = ThmxTheme.Open(web.Site, themeUrl);
    string themeName = currentTheme.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But i need to get the current theme name which is applied to the site.
From the code you have mentioned i cant get the current applied theme name.

Comment: I tried this code long back but getting themeUrl variable as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, all the above APIs did not give the current theme name value, so I am getting this value from the design catalog.

You can try the below code, to get the theme name and let me know whether this works for you or we have any other better way to achieve the same.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to get the theme from desing catalog
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Theme name</returns>
    private static string GetThemeFromDesignCatalog()
    {
        var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var designGallery = web.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.DesignCatalog);
        var CurrentThemeItems = GetCurrentTheme(designGallery);
        if (CurrentThemeItems != null && CurrentThemeItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SPItem item in CurrentThemeItems)
            {
                var themeURLArray = GetArrayValue(themeURL, item);
                var masterPageURLArray = GetArrayValue(masterPageURL, item);
                if (themeURLArray.Length > 1 && masterPageURLArray.Length > 1)
                {
                    var themeURLValue = themeURLArray[1].Trim();
                    var masterPageURLValue = masterPageURLArray[1].Trim();
                    var AppliedThemes = GetAppliedThemeName(designGallery, themeURLValue, masterPageURLValue);
                    if (AppliedThemes != null && AppliedThemes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var name = AppliedThemes[0]["Name"];
                        if (name != null)
                        {
                            return name.ToString().Trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to query the design catalog and find the matching theme for the given
    /// theme URL and Master Page URL
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="designGallery">Design gallery</param>
    /// <param name="themeURLValue">Theme URL Value</param>
    /// <param name="masterPageURLValue">Master Page URL value</param>
    /// <returns>Applied themes</returns>
    private static SPListItemCollection GetAppliedThemeName(SPList designGallery, string themeURLValue, string masterPageURLValue)
    {
        var matchingThemeQuery = new SPQuery();
        matchingThemeQuery.RowLimit = 1;
        var themeURLQuery = "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ThemeUrl'/><Value Type='URL'>" + themeURLValue + "</Value></Eq>";
        var masterUrl = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='MasterPageUrl'/><Value Type='URL'>" + masterPageURLValue + "</Value></Eq></And>";
        var displayOrder = "<Neq><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Neq>";
        matchingThemeQuery.Query = "<Where><And>" + themeURLQuery + masterUrl + displayOrder + "</And></Where>";
        matchingThemeQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>";
        matchingThemeQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        var matchingThemeItems = designGallery.GetItems(matchingThemeQuery);
        return matchingThemeItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to query the design catalog and get the current theme item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="designGallery">Design gallery</param>
    /// <returns>Current Theme</returns>
    private static SPListItemCollection GetCurrentTheme(SPList designGallery)
    {
        var currentTheme = new SPQuery();
        currentTheme.RowLimit = 1;
        currentTheme.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Eq></Where>";
        currentTheme.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ThemeUrl'/><FieldRef Name='MasterPageUrl'/>";
        currentTheme.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        var currentItems = designGallery.GetItems(currentTheme);
        return currentItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to get theme and master page URL in the format of array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName">Column Name of the list item</param>
    /// <param name="item">List item</param>
    /// <returns>Array with URL and its description value</returns>
    private static string[] GetArrayValue(string columnName, SPItem item)
    {
        return (item[columnName] != null) ? item[columnName].ToString().Split(',') : new string[0];
    }
```

Regards,
Kalai.